# How do i query and select a specific date

Tags: php, mysql

How do i query and select only the date. Because in my database the value is in datettime. I only want to select the date in my query, it is giving me and error. But when i put the time it is working.

Here is my query

```
 sql =  "SELECT teamone,teamtwo,s_name, s_gender, start, end, v_name FROM `sport` 
    inner JOIN `matches` ON `matches`.`s_id` = `sport`.`s_id` left JOIN `schedule` ON  
`schedule`.`m_id` = `matches`.`m_id` left join `venue` ON `schedule`.`v_id` = `venue`.`v_id`
        Where start = '2016-12-09 10:00:00' ORDER by start asc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Start is a datetime or timestamp. You need only date u must be 'date' for data type. If you use datetime or timestamp u must be '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
[mysql date and times data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html).
You can use this site for questions.

Comment: The data type is in datettime

Comment: Yes if you used datetime you must use this style '0000-00-00 00:00:00' . If you can change type, you can use date. Or if you cant, you can use 'Where start = '2016-12-09 % ' ORDER by start asc'..